# Как использовать цикл while вместе с Телеграм ботом?

Tags: python, aiogram

Каждый `period` секунд я беру скриншот камеры.

```
player = vlc.MediaPlayer('rtsp://nnnnnnnnn')
player.play() 
while True:
    player.video_take_snapshot(0, './screenshot.tmp.jpg', 0, 0)
    time.sleep(period)
```

Взятый скриншот обрабатывается и высылается в ботом в чат (пользователю)

Этот цикл я хочу вставить в Телеграм бота, на aiogram.
**Но как это сделать?** Ведь цикл бесконечный. Как запустить, собственно, все то, что должно работать после цикла?

Это часть кода самого бота, где уже обработанное изображение высылается в чат:

```
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Этот бот будет отправлять в чат фотографии')
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 
                           photo=types.FSInputFile('results_screenshot.tmp.jpg'))
    await message.send_message(f'Найдено {counts} объектов')
```

Comment: [Скорее всего это то что вам нужно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/how-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds)

Comment: Так отправление изображения происходит не после цикла, а в самом цикле.